# Using jQuery's function that contains css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm super new to coding and I was trying to make a simple color game using jQuery. To put it short, 4 options, click the right one, an alert pops out. 
I randomly put the answer in an array ( colors[] ) along with other dummies, and then use that array to put into css.

```
  var dummy = '#aaa';
  var answer = '#ee00aa';

  var colors = [dummy,answer,dummy,dummy];

  for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    $('#colorBox'+i).css('background', ''+colors[i-1]+'');
  }

  $('#colorBox'+i).click(function() {
    if ($(this).css('background', ''+colors[answer]+'') == true) {
      alert("Gratz!");
    }
```

The problem is, I cant find a way to define the answer for this click function to work. Thanks.

Comment: `$(this).css('background', ''+colors[answer]+'')` You are setting the background color, not getting its value.

Comment: Do you know any way to getting its value @IvankaTodorova ? Or maybe a link to somewhere I could read about this section?

Comment: Just don't pass a second argument to `.css('background')`

Comment: Aside from the syntax and logic issues, I'd suggest you apply classes to the colourBox elements as checking for the background colour CSS property is inconsistent. Some browsers return RGB, some hex, for example.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova there are a lot more issues than that

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan do you mean like addClass() to it? If the one with the right colors[ ] is clicked, an alert pops out, does it matter what type it returns?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you're correct. :) Wonder why it was downvoted, tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issue with your code above.

- Use the getter of `css()` in the condition and compare it directly to the `answer` string, as `colors[answer]` is invalid.
- You don't need to repeatedly append empty strings.
- You should put the `click` handler code inside the loop, as it relies on the `i` variable

There is one final, much larger, problem with this logic though. That is that when retrieving colours from CSS properties some browsers return hex values and others RGB. Therefore your comparison to a hex value will easily be broken.

A better solution would be to apply classes to elements to make it easier to determine which is the correct answer. You can also use classes to group common elements with a single instead of incremental `id` attributes. You can also use the initial loop to build the HTML. Something like this:

```js
var classes = ['d', 'a', 'd', 'd'];
var $container = $('.container');

var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
 html += '<div class="colorbox ' + classes[i] + '"></div>';
}
$container.append(html).on('click', '.colorbox', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('a')) {
        alert("Gratz!");
    }
});
```

```css
.colorbox {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.colorbox.a {
    background-color: #ee00aa;
}
.colorbox.d {
    background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Ok now I get what you meant earlier.

What if I want to write this code without using class as you suggested? Using class is a very good way of solving it but I would prefer not to because I want to make RGB a variable so that it would change everytime the right answer is clicked.

Comment: var color = $(this).css('background');if ( color == ans )